# How to use TortoiseSVN via command line?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN and want to use command line SVN options.

I used the command:

```
svn checkout [-N] [--ignore-externals] [-r rev] URL PATH
```

and get the following error:

> 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Is it because I need to add some environment variable? Or can't TortoiseSVN be used from the command line?

Comment: I'd suggest [slik subversion](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download). And after installing just add its bin directory to your path. -bhups

Comment: I usually have the standard SVN installed as well as TortoiseSVN. Just add the binary location of SVN to your PATH environment variable. Using the standard SVN command line tool will be better for getting help and documentation than using any other SVN pseudo client.

Comment: It adds itself to the PATH on installation anyway.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is probably the most used Windows GUI SVN client there is and it's thoroughly documented. I wouldn't call it pseudo-client just because it's not the reference command-line implementation.

Comment: I meant the command line TSVN - not the GUI one.  A different poster suggested to use the TSVN command line - which, I gather, is not the same as using SVN.  My point is that if you are going to use tsvn, use it as intended - as a GUI client.  If you are going to use command line, use the original...

Comment: That's exactly what the docs say, too :-)

Comment: The latest version of TortoiseSVN (1.7.1 of this writing) has an option during installation for command line tools. It is not turned on by default but it will install the standard command line files for svn. So there is no need to install a separate subversion package like Silk anymore.

Comment: Just a quick FYI, if using Slik svn and you get that error : " 'svn' is not recognized... " you might have to open System Properties dialogue. While Slik does add the correct entry to your Path variable, you might have to click edit and 'ok' (even if you haven't made any changes) to enable the variable. At least that was my experience using Windows Vista. After I did that, Windows recognized the change in the Path and my svn command was recognized.

Comment: I have added the SlikSvn/bin path to the environment variable but still get this error...

Answer (score 502, accepted):

By default TortoiseSVN always has a GUI (Graphical User Interface) associated with it. But on the installer (of version 1.7 and later) you can select the "command line client tools" option so you can call svn commands (like svn commit and svn update) from the command line.

Here's a screenshot of the "command line client tools" option in the installer, you need to make sure you select it:

[image: How-to-install-TortoiseSvn-CommandLineTools]

Comment: Personally, I prefer this answer to the accepted one: no secondary installations, and full access to the standard SVN command line.

Comment: Also has the added benefit that the command line tool versions stay in sync with the TortoiseSVN version.

Comment: ... which means, in more detail: the working directory format of Subversion has changed a few times, e.g. in versions 1.7 and 1.8. An 1.7 client won't use an older working directory unless it is `svn upgrade`d; after that, an 1.6 client won't be able to use it anymore.

Comment: As a tip, if you already have Tortoise installed, there is no need to reinstall. You can simply open up the original installer .msi file, and instead of choosing "Uninstall" you can choose "Modify." It will just update your current Tortoise installation without messing anything up.

Comment: Seems a popular issue. Interesting why the installation setup still with the disabled option for the console tools...

Comment: As a tip, if you already have Tortoise installed, *and don't have the .msi file* - you can go to the Control Panel -> Programs and Features, and then select the TortoiseSVN -> Modify.

Comment: To open this client in Windows, you go to Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs -> TortoiseSVN.  Right click and select Modify.

Comment: If you have to add this feature programmatically (i.e. via a script), add "CLI" on the installation command line: msiexec /i "TortoiseSVN-x.yy.zzzz-x64-svn-x.yy.msi" ADDLOCAL="F_OVL,DefaultFeature,MoreIcons,CLI,CrashReporter,UDiffAssoc,DictionaryENGB,DictionaryENUS"

Answer (score 131):

TortoiseSVN has a command-line interface that can be used for TortoiseSVN GUI automation and it's different from the normal Subversion one.

You can find information about the command-line options of TortoiseSVN in the documentation:
[Appendix D. Automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html). The main program to work with here is `TortoiseProc.exe`.

**But a note pretty much at the top there already says:**

> **Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead.**

Another option would be that you install the Subversion binaries. [Slik SVN](http://sliksvn.com/en/download/) is a nice build (and doesn't require a registration like Collabnet). Recent versions of TortoiseSVN also include the command-line client if you choose to install it.

Comment: Just to add to this - make sure Tortoise is on your path. Otherwise, nothing will work.

Comment: Based on this answer, I think the best bet would be to install the actual SVN command-line client rather than learn a second command-line interface.  I don't know how to do that, though.

Comment: Thomas: By default both TortoiseSVN and Slik SVN will alter the path accordingly.

Comment: Where i check that ok button in the settings ?
I couldn't find that option there .
thanks

Comment: Night Walker: If you like to register for something as mundane as a build of publicly available sources, then sure, go ahead. I included a link to an alternative, though.

Comment: It seems much more sensible to me to install the standard svn command line tools when installing svn and use those commands. Using TortoiseProc is a very weird and roundabout way to use svn commands.

Comment: This solution is simply out of date, the TortosieSVN installer now includes the command line tools.

Comment: You may need to reboot after installation so that you get the change to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. TortoiseProc.exe that you reference should be used only for GUI automation. It is not a replacement for command line `svn.exe` client. **TortoiseProc.exe is NOT an alternative to svn.exe command line client**.

Comment: @bahrep: Well, after your edit it's definitely not misleading, I think.

Answer (score 110):

In case you have already installed the TortoiseSVN GUI and wondering how to upgrade to command line tools, here are the steps...

1. Go to Windows Control Panel → *Program and Features* (Windows 7+)
2. Locate TortoiseSVN and click on it.
3. Select "Change" from the options available.
4. Refer to this image for further steps.

   [image: TortoiseSVN Command Line Enable]
5. After completion of the command line client tools, open a command prompt and type `svn help` to check the successful install.

Comment: Your answer was not formatted already. And it had unwanted information. He did both formatting and editing your answer properly. Please read the help center for more. ;)

Comment: Win10 is "Apps & Features".. but that's probably obvious

Comment: Ok don't believe me. Please ask this as a question in meta whether the edit is legitimate or not. He not only formatted your answer, he also did remove unwanted information which is not required for the answer. It's called moderation. And people with high reps generally do clean up the site by moderating and contributing which is why I suggested you to look up the help centre. But you just want to argue instead of gaining knowledge. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah actually I am interested in sharing the knowledge and not to claim someone's work and preach. Also I am not a blind follower of high reps.

Comment: while we enable command line, it ask for application path which is required to download. path : https://osdn.net/projects/tortoisesvn/storage/1.12.0/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.12.0.28568-x64-svn-1.12.0.msi/

Comment: Using TortoiseSVN 1.7.6.22632 (64 bit) I see the Unistall option only

Comment: This still works for windows 11 and when I didn't have the msi file, I was able to redownload it from here: https://www.download3k.com/Install-The-TortoiseSVN-team-TortoiseSVN.html

Answer (score 30):

To use command support you should follow this steps:

1. Define Path in Environment Variables:

   - open '**System Properties**';
   - on the tab '**Advanced**' click on the '**Environment Variables**' button
   - in the section '**System variables**' select '**Path**' option and click '**edit**'
   - append variable value with the path to **TortoiseProc.exe** file, for example:

     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
2. Since you have registered **TortoiseProc**, you can use it in according to TortoiseSVN [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html).

   **Examples:**

   TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit
                    /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt*c:\svn_wc\file2.txt"
                    /logmsg:"test log message" /closeonend:0

   TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\svn_wc\" /closeonend:0

   TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt"
                    /startrev:50 /endrev:60 /closeonend:0

P.S. To use friendly name like 'svn' instead of 'TortoiseProc', place 'svn.bat' file in the directory of 'TortoiseProc.exe'. There is an example of svn.bat:

```
TortoiseProc.exe %1 %2 %3
```

Comment: The main problem is not the name of the executable (and how to find it) but the totally different commandline syntax; see my answer which tells about my `tsvn` program (which didn't exist at the time of Warlock's answer).  Recent Windows versions allow to specify all arguments as `%*` (instead of `%1 %2 %3` ...).

Answer (score 10):

To enable svn run the TortoiseSVN installation program again, select "Modify" (Allows users to change the way features are installed) and install "command line client tools".

Comment: for those of you who are wondering where the "Modify" option is - try to re-install Tortoise SVN

Comment: @maya If you have already installed it don't try to uninstall and re-install it. Go to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` search Tortoise SVN and click `Change` and then click on `Modify`.

Answer (score 10):

My solution was to use [DOSKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY) to set up some aliases to for the commands I use the most:

```
DOSKEY svc=TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:.
DOSKEY svu=TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:.
DOSKEY svl=TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:.
DOSKEY svd=TortoiseProc.exe /command:diff /path:$*
```

Google "doskey persist" for tips on how to set up a .cmd file that runs every time you open the command prompt like a .*rc file in Unix.

Comment: Great! This is the only answer that actually invokes TortoiseSVN, not ordinary `svn`, from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You can have both TortoiseSVN and the Apache Subversion command line tools installed.  I usually install the Apache SVN tools from the VisualSVN download site: https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/

Once installed, place the Subversion\bin in your set PATH.  Then you will be able to use TortoiseSVN when you want to use the GUI, and you have the proper SVN command line tools to use from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

There is a confusion that is causing a lot of TortoiseSVN users to use the wrong command line tools when they actually were looking for `svn.exe` command line client.

> What should I do or can't TortoiseSVN be used from the command line?

### svn.exe

If you want to run Subversion commands from the command prompt, you should run the [`svn.exe`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/) command line client. TortoiseSVN 1.6.x and older versions did not include SVN command-line tools, but modern versions do.

If you want to get SVN command line tools without having to install TortoiseSVN, check the [SVN binary distributions page](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) or simply download the latest version from [VisualSVN downloads page](https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/).

If you have SVN command line tools installed on your system, but still get the error `'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, you should check `%PATH%` environment variable. `%PATH%` must include the path to SVN tools directory e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin`.

### TortoiseProc.exe

Apart from `svn.exe`, TortoiseSVN comes with `TortoiseProc.exe` that can be called from command prompt. In most cases, you do **not** need to use this tool, because it should be only used for GUI automation. `TortoiseProc.exe` is not a replacement for SVN command-line client.

Answer (score 2):

As Joey pointed out, TortoiseSVN has a commandline syntax of its own.  Unfortunately it is quite ugly, if you are used to `svn` commands, and it ignores the current working directory, thus it is not very usable - except for scripting.

I have created a little Python program (`tsvn`) which mimics the `svn` commandline syntax as closely as possible and calls TortoiseSVN accordingly.  Thus, the difference between calling the normal commandline tools and calling TortoiseSVN is reduced to a little letter `t` at the beginning.

My `tsvn` program is not yet complete but already useful. It can be found in the cheeseshop (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tsvn/)

Comment: For those not familiar with Python: you need a recent Python 2.x interpreter. If you have `easy_install` or `pip install`, just specify `tsvn`; otherwise you can download and extract the tarball and run the contained `setup.py` installation script.  Since it is interpreted, you can inspect it in full detail ;-)

Answer (score 2):

After some time, I used this workaround...

(at the .bat file)

```
SET "CHECKOUT=http://yoururl.url";
SET "PATH=your_folder_path"

start "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin" svn.exe checkout %CHECKOUT% %PATH%
```

Answer (score 2):

My fix for getting SVN commands was to copy .exe and .dll files from the TortoiseSVN directory and pasting them into system32 folder.

You could also perform the command from the TortoiseSVN directory and add the path of the working directory to each command. For example:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin> svn st -v C:\checkout
```

Adding the bin to the path should make it work without duplicating the files, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: This approach is not working, still shows ```'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command```

Answer (score 0):

After selecting "SVN command line tools" it will become like this:

[image]

Comment: This is the desired outcome, however this answer does not tell how to actually achieve this.