# How to use the SVN command line with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

How do I use the command line for SVN when SVN is installed by Tortoise?

I'm trying to invoke some commands found in *[Changing a revision property in Subversion](http://jacqueschirag.wordpress.com/2007/07/22/changing-revision-property-in-subversion-with-tortoisesvn/)*, but I'm not seeing the same directory structure under `Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server` (obviously).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625406/using-tortoisesvn-via-the-command-line

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That page mostly references setting up SVN hooks on the *server*, but you can call SVN functions through Tortoise like the following:

```
<Path to TortoiseSVN>\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:<SVNCommand> <Parameters>
```

For example:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\MyRepo\"
```

Reference here: [Automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

Comment: TortoiseProc.exe is a GUI program and the "output" will be windows with some information in them, not text to standard output.

Comment: How we can pass username and password?

Answer (score 3):

The directory structure is per repository. You have to look at your *repository*'s folder, not the program folder.

Comment: ok, I tried to cd to repositories and also repositories\repoName and tried to run that mv .... command.  I must be missing something here.

Comment: Did you look in your working copy or in the _repository_? (The latter is on the _server_, the former on the client.)

Comment: How to use `svn update [-r rev] [-depth ARG] [--ignore-externals] PATH`