# storing multiple credentials in tortoisesvn

Tags: tortoisesvn, projects, credentials

I am working on several projects in different subversion repositories using tortoise. How do I save the credentials for all my projects so I don't have to enter username/password everytime? If I save the credentials, only the latest credentials are saved, forcing me to clear the cache before using tortoise on another project.

thanks
Thomas

Comment: What protocol are you connecting through?  Examples at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html

Comment: All repositories are hosted with xp-dev.com through http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials are saved for every authentication realm string.
If you want to use different auth data for different repositories, include the repository name in the realm string of your server.

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thank you for your answer. I am not very familiar with the details of subversion and tortoisesvn. How do I do what you propose? Thanks

Comment: the realm string is set and configured on the server, in its config file.

Comment: I don't have access to the server as such, since the repositories are hosted at xp-dev.com. I only have access to the repositories

Comment: In that case you have to ask the guys at xp-dev.com to configure the realm string properly.

Answer (score 6):

I also use XP-Dev with more than one login and had the same issue.

I used the following svn command line to do the initial checkout:

```
svn checkout http://xp-dev.com/svn/ProjectName  c:\dev\projectfolder --username myusername --password mypassword
```

This checked out the project and the credentials were saved so that Tortoise SVN worked following this.

Comment: btw, here is step to activate `command-line` svn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874961/2377343

Answer (score 1):

Go in TortoiseSVN -> Settings-> Store Data
Click the clear button. Than I will ask you login on each push

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzTYS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround if you have only 2 credentials: for 1 of them, replace the address xp-dev.com with its IP address so that from SVN Tortoise point of view, there are 2 distinct servers.