# using tortoise svn for updating source code in maven

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3

i am using the `scm plugin` in maven to *update* svn code each time i take a build. The goal specified for the plugin is update. I have tortoise svn installed in my system but when i execute the build it fails saying that svn update `command not found`. I realised that i need to install another svn client (like silk subversion) and then it works. So is there any way by which i can use tortoise svn only and execute the build or do i have to install another svn client?
Also if i do use another svn client then will it anyway affect tortoise svn or cause any problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use svn command line client for the scm plugin to work.

Also installing a command line svn client does not affect tortoise svn in any way.

Comment: thanks vizier..i came across this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625406/using-tortoisesvn-via-the-command-line where they've mentioned that the command line part of tortoise svn can be installed too..so on doing that do i need to change anything in pom for scm to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [svn-provider instead of the command line](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/maven-scm-provider-svnjava/) tools of SVN but the best is to install SVN command line client and not TortoiseSVN etc. I'm not sure if there are some compatibility issues between TortoiseSVN CLI and SVN CLI.

Comment: thanks khmarbaise, actually i am already using TortoiseSVN and should not uninstall it. So just wanted to know if there may be issues using two clients on same machine