# Checking basic SVN info from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tortoisesvn

I have programmed a *customized* deployment routine in **.NET** which does the following:

1. Performs some previous checks on my code (among other things). This code is placed in a local folder.
2. If all tests are OK it will then transfer this code to the production server.

Now, my question is: as a "previous check", I would like to test if my local folder contains the latest update from my **Tortoise SVN** repository. Is there any info in the .svn folders to check if an update is needed, or any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any info in the .svn folders to check if an update is needed

No

> or any other way to do so?

Yes.

You have to use `svn status -u` ("show updates") from your app (if you have CLI svn-client) and check output.

From `svn help status`

```
   The out-of-date information appears in the ninth column (with -u):
      '*' a newer revision exists on the server
      ' ' the working copy is up to date
```

Sample:

```
>svn status -u wc
 M             965   wc/bar.c
        *      965   wc/foo.c
A  +             -   wc/qax.c
Status against revision:   981
```

wc/bar.c contains local modifications
wc/foo.c updated in repository
wc/qax.c added locally and sheduled for commit

in case of none local changes and repository changes

```
>svn status -u
Status against revision:     37
```

You will not get file-list, only status-line

Comment: Than you very much for the hint. So now I have read have read about these functionalities [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html). Then I decided that a good option was to test through errorCodes what is the state of my local folder:

`process.Start()
process.WaitForExit()
Return process.ExitCode`

The thing is that with this method I can know if a *commit* is necessary (with cmd="my_folder -n"), but not if an *update* is necessary...

Furthermore, I can not find any "-u" option in the documentation.

Comment: OK, I gathered more information and now I see what I was missing. The first and more important piece is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625406/using-tortoisesvn-via-the-command-line) (answer by AnneTheAgile): in tortoise, "command line client tools" is not installed by default. After installing them you can use svn.exe. So now your suggestion (svn status -u) works like a charm, thanks.