# Compare two SVN revisions with beyond compare 4

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I try to compare two revisions with the folder compare of Beyond Compare 4.
But I fail to connect my SVN-folder, I get an error.

[image]

When I connect to the SVN-repository with my TortoiseSVN, I'm asked for user and password and I'm connected without problems.

What do I need in addition to compare SCN-revisions with the folder compare of Beyond Compare 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond Compare 4 uses SVN via the command line, but the installation of TortoiseSVN does not install the command line by default.

After the [installation of the command line client tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874961/676874) the `svn.exe`-command is availabe and beyond compare can connect to SVN.

Now you can compare two SVN-revisions in the folder compare:
[image]