# How to install PyLucene 6.0.2 in windows

Tags: python, lucene, pylucene

I'm trying to create a simple application on the Information Retreival using `python` & `PyLucene`.

Can you help me to install PyLucene 6.2.0 on windows , I already installed `jcc` , but i didn't know how to install PyLucene.

I found this documentation http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html#for-the-rest-of-us but i didn't understand what is make & install make instructions.

Please help me .

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I didn't understand what is [make] (http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html#for-the-impatient-ones)

Comment: `make` is a command for Lunix , but how about windows ? what shoul I do ?

Comment: @Asma , did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have SVN command line tools installed.

Follow this link for SVN - [Using TortoiseSVN via the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1625406/11631110)

Then install "[Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)"

Also, you can directly download '**Make for windows**' from here - https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/postdownload

After that you can use **make** in your command prompt.