# SVN not working in command line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I work with Eclipse and use SVN as a VersionControlSystem. I also have TortoiseSVN installed on my PC.

When I'm updating or commiting via mouse by right-click and the Team list option everything works. But I read, that it is even easier to use the command prompt.

Now when I try ty input `svn --version` or `svn --status` on the project path I get the message, that the command can not be found.
How can I fix this?

My current versions:

TortoiseSVN 1.8.11

SubversiveSVN 4.0.5

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fix this by re-running the Tortoise SVN installer and opting to install the command-line utilities. If you've previously done this and it's still not working (even after a reboot), then you'll need to add `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin` (or whatever is the appropriate path to your TortoiseSVN installation) to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, the command-line utilitiy wasn't installed. Everything works fine now.

Comment: yes rerunning the tortoise svn installation, solve the issue (Y) thanks Alroc

Answer (score 0):

@alroc answer can't solve my problem. I found the solution for me:Run the **TortoiseSVN.msi** file to add the command line tool.below is the reference:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077456/6399074