# SVN Tortoise update using PHP

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn

I had a problem on PHP I used `proc_open` to open the exe file.

but I received error.

> **Error:**  'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here's the code to call the process.

**CODE:**

```
$process = proc_open('"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" update "c:\xampp2\htdocs\test_tills"',
                 $descriptorspec,
                 $pipes);
```

Comment: There is a problem with quotes that causes this particular issue. However, you should not be using TortoieseProc.exe at all. You should be using `svn.exe`. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44779536/761095

Comment: that answer was 9 years ago. and now they are using TortoiseProc.exe