# Check SVN Folder externals via System Command Line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, external, svn-externals

i currently try to access the list of all externals in a specific folder via the system command line.
I tried following follwing command:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command: propget svn:externals -R
```

Can somebody help me with that ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use the regular command line interface for working with SVN on the command line:

`svn propget svn:externals -R`

If you don't have the svn command installed with your TortoiseSVN, you can easily do that by modifying your current installation. This answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077456/14627587

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it out but I want to use this command in Matlab via the system command line for scripting. So therefore i need somehow execute it from the system command line. Do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: That's what I mean. ```svn``` is a command line application.TortoiseProc.exe is a GUI tool for the same functionality. If you are on windows and use Tortoise you may not have this installed right away, but it is part of the package. So just make sure if you type ```svn help``` in cmd that you get a proper answer and then you can use it like the command you posted above.