# How to remove untracked files in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

How can I remove all untracked files from an SVN checkout with the `svn` command line tool? Git and Hg offer `clean` and `purge` commands for this purpose, but I can't find the corresponding command in SVN.

I don't care if I have to revert all my local modifications in the process (in which case I'd essentially want to restore my checkout to a pristine state) or whether local modifications to tracked files can remain intact; either situation is acceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete all unversioned/ignored files/folders in my working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803823/how-can-i-delete-all-unversioned-ignored-files-folders-in-my-working-copy)

Comment: @Ruslan: Even though my question isn't about TortoiseSVN, yes, that's essentially the same point.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There may be a built-in way, but if so, I don't know of it.  However, something like the following should do the job:

```
svn st | grep '^?' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

(All unversioned files should appear in a line beginning with `?` in an `svn st`.)

**EDIT ([@GearoidMurphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300745/gearoid-murphy))**
It's challenging to get this snippet to work on a cygwin environment, as xargs treats the windows path slashes as escape sequences and has trouble parsing the '\r\n' line endings, below is my adapted solution of this perfectly valid answer:

```
svn st | grep '^?' | gawk '{printf(\"%s|\", $2)}' | xargs -d "|" -n1 C:\cygwin\bin\rm -r
```

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that may have to do, though it's formidably ugly, and it requires several extra non-SVN tools.

Comment: This doesn't take account of ignored files, so you may also need the `--no-ignore` flag to `svn st`

Comment: Also I think this may perhaps fail for filenames containing spaces

Comment: This will work for filenames with spaces: `svn st | grep '^?' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} rm -rf '{}'`

Comment: To remove the ignored files, you'd need to use `svn st --no-ignore | grep '^I' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf`. `svn st --no-ignore` starts the line with an `I` for ignored files.

Comment: I was googling on how to remove the untracked files with `svn` keeping in mind `awk` and was hoping to find a better solution. Didn't work out apparently.

Comment: To properly handle filenames with space, I had to make one more change to @NickGarvey's snippet: `svn st | grep '^?' | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | xargs -I{} rm -rf '{}'`. Note changed `awk` command based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635/using-awk-to-print-all-columns-from-the-nth-to-the-last.

Comment: If no `-v` is given, there are exactly 9 columns before the path. So an alternative is `svn st | grep '^?' | cut -c9- | while read fname; do rm -rf "$fname"; done` (using while allows for multiple commands, even conditionals for each file)

Comment: `svn st | grep '^?' | cut -d' ' -f8- | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs rm -rf`

Answer (score 52):

Since version 1.9, you can use the following:

```
svn cleanup . --remove-unversioned
```

See https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-cleanup-options

Comment: Ding ding ding! The best answer in 2018.

Comment: --remove-ignored is required as well

Answer (score 21):

The [svn-clean](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn-clean) script does precisely this, though it does rely on having perl installed. It will leave local modifications intact but will remove ignored files.  Run with '-p' to preview the files that will be removed.

Answer (score 5):

This command should do the job, spaces and all (tried on OSX only):

```
svn status | grep '^\?' | sed 's/? *//' | xargs -I%  rm -fr %
```