# svn: cleanup/revert recursively a folder to make sure that it has no files that aren't part of SVN

Tags: svn

When I recursively cleanup a folder in SVN I have some files that aren't part of SVN (e.g. `svn status` lists them with a `?`). So, my question is: how do I tell SVN to delete all these files, so that my svn status would return empty, e.g. identical to SVN server.

one way would be:

```
rm -r /path/to/localcopy/somefolder && svn update /path/to/localcopy/somefolder
```

but this isn't acceptable, because that somefolder contains LOTS of files that I don't want to checkout everytime.

Comment: Just a note: svn `cleanup` is not for discarding local changes, `revert` does.  Just a reminder to avoid misunderstanding  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updated to work with file paths containing whitespace, except for newlines. Tested in bash 3.2.17 on Mac OS X.

Also see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803823/how-can-i-delete-all-unversioned-ignored-files-folders-in-my-working-copy).

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for path in $(svn st | awk '/^\?/ { $1=""; print substr($0, 2) }'); do
    rm -r "$path"
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Let's break this down.

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
```

Saves the old value of `$IFS` (the shell's input field separator) and changes the value to a newline. This will let us loop over things containing spaces, only going to the next iteration when we hit a newline character.

```
for path in $( ...
```

Loop through the results of the command substitution inside `$( )`.

```
svn st | awk '/^\?/ ...
```

Prints all lines from `svn st` (same as `svn status`) that begin with `?`.

```
{ $1=""; print substr($0, 2) }'
```

Removes `?` and leading whitespaces, leaving only the un-versioned paths in your working copy.

```
    rm -r "$path"
```

Delete the path, passing `-r` in case the path is a directory. There's no need to check if the path is a directory because an un-versioned directory can't contain versioned content.

```
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Restore the value of the shell's input field separator.