# Deleting all new local files svn status shows as `?`

Tags: svn

Is there an easy way to delete all local files that `svn status` shows as `?`, meaning new, not yet been added or checked in?

I do `svn revert -R .` to revert all the changed files but that doesn't do anything to the files that are new. I would like a 100% sync up with the repo, as though I completely checked everything out anew.

Comment: You can: svn cleanup . --remove-unversioned See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803823/how-can-i-delete-all-unversioned-ignored-files-folders-in-my-working-copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `svn cleanup`. It accepts a few switches, but for what you're trying to do, which is deleting the *unversioned* files, you want to add the `--remove-unversioned` switch. This will delete all of the files under that directory that are not under version control.

```
svn cleanup /path/to/folder --remove-unversioned
```

Comment: @amphibient Really? If you run `svn cleanup help` in the command line, do you see any available switches you can use?

Comment: @amphibient So I'm assuming you don't have subversion 1.9 if that's the case. If so, you might want to have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239340/automatically-remove-subversion-unversioned-files/239358#239358