# How to do a sparse checkout and update from SVN on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, sparse-checkout

We have a large SVN repository and I would like to do a sparse checkout on Jenkins. I do understand the concept of sparse checkouts and having it locally I can get things to work as I would like to have it. Doing things on Jenkins however and running it repeatedly I can't get to work.

I have a repo structure as follows

```
trunk\file.txt
trunk\FolderA
trunk\FolderB
trunk\FolderC
trunk\FolderD
```

I would like to checkout and update

```
trunk\file.txt
trunk\FolderA
trunk\FolderB
```

but *NOT*

```
trunk\FolderC
trunk\FolderD
```

My pipeline code is as follows

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
    additionalCredentials: [[credentialsId: strCredentialsId, realm: strRealm]],
    excludedCommitMessages: '', 
    excludedRegions: '', 
    excludedRevprop: '', 
    excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, 
    ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
    includedRegions: '', 
    locations: [
        [
            remote: "${strRepoPath}/trunk",
            local: "${softwarePath}", 
            depthOption: 'unknown', 
            credentialsId: strCredentialsId,
            cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
            ignoreExternalsOption: false
        ],
        [
            remote: "${strRepoPath}/trunk/FolderA",
            local: "${softwarePath}/FolderA", 
            depthOption: 'infinity', 
            credentialsId: strCredentialsId, 
            cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
            ignoreExternalsOption: false
        ],
        [
            remote: "${strRepoPath}/trunk/FolderB",
            local: "${softwarePath}/FolderB", 
            depthOption: 'infinity', 
            credentialsId: strCredentialsId, 
            cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
            ignoreExternalsOption: false
        ]
    ],
    quietOperation: false, 
    workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateWithCleanUpdater']])
```

Whenever I run this code the first time, everything looks as expected. However, when Jenkins runs it the following times, the *UpdateWithCleanUpdater* causes that FolderA and FolderB get first deleted and then checked out again. The result is still correct, however, it takes much longer that I would like it to take and longer than necessary.

I would like to keep the *UpdateWithCleanUpdater* because I want Jenkins to clean up files generated in the previous run.

Is there any solution to this using the Jenkins SVN plugin? How would I do this "manually", i.e. do a checkout the first time, clean up and only update the following times, and still do automatic Jenkins runs based on change detection on the SVN repo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Now *that* is a very narrow issue.
I'd say, either you replace the *UpdateWithCleanUpdater* with a manual script (by calling your local svn client; some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803823/how-can-i-delete-all-unversioned-ignored-files-folders-in-my-working-copy)); or you could fork or contribute to the Jenkins [SVN plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin).

Comment: This might work, however seems to be very inconvenient, because every file/folder needs to be handled separately. FolderA and FolderB are considered as unversioned when looking at the root directory trunk/. _svn info_ is showing _?_ for these folders

Comment: With the _svn info is showing ?_ you might be in the situation that I called "normal checkout into another SVN workspace", in my answer. The commands to do the "sparse checkout" look like: `svn checkout --depth empty https://yourRepo workspace ; svn update --set-depth empty workspace/trunk ; svn update workspace/trunk/FolderA workspace/trunk/file.txt workspace/trunk/FolderB`

Answer (score 1):

The very first location with `${strRepoPath}/trunk` can be completely removed. That will probably resolve the issue. However, Jenkins does not seem to support a 'true' sparse checkout from SVN. The result will be two checkouts into two local workspaces.